# Material para estudo de linguagens funcionais: scala, haskell e erlang

Tags: scala, haskell, erlang

Bom, fiz uma pergunta recentemente e a mesma foi suspensa por ser questão de opinião de cada pessoa, então aqui refaço minha pergunta pra ficar mais claro o que eu quero:

Alguém por favor poderia me passar sites ou indicar livros para aprendizado das seguintes linguagens:

- Scala
- Erlang
- Haskell

Só pra esclarecer não to pedindo pdf de nada, só indicação de livros e sites que tratem do assunto =)

Tenho alguns links e materiais dos mesmos, porém a maioria estão em inglês e tratam superficialmente do assunto, se alguém souber só em inglês mesmo não tem problema, porém se tiver em português eu vou preferir.

Desde já eu agradeço!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Scala

1. [**Um tutorial de Scala**](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaTutorial-pt_BR.pdf) - para programadores Java
2. [**Introdução a linguagem Scala**](http://sobrecodigo.com/introducao-a-linguagem-scala/)
3. [**Lista de discussão em Português**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-br)
4. [**Programming in Scala, First Edition**](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) - por Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, and Bill Venners - Inglês

   Existe a segunda versão do livro **Programming in Scala** porém, [não é gratuito](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033073.do).

### Erlang

1. [**Programando Erlang - #1**](http://eliasdorneles.github.io/2014/04/05/programando-erlang---1-de-any.html)
2. [**Conceitos fundamentais de ERLANG – Parte 1**](http://elemarjr.net/2011/08/07/conceitos-fundamentais-de-erlang-parte-1-de-3/)
3. [**Conceitos fundamentais de ERLANG – Parte 2**](http://elemarjr.net/2011/08/09/conceitos-fundamentais-de-erlang-parte-2-de-3/)
4. [**Concurrent Programming in Erlang Second Edition**](http://www.erlang.org/download/erlang-book-part1.pdf) - Inglês
5. [**Learn you some Erlang**](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/contents) - Em inglês, porém muito completo.

### Haskell

1. [**Aprender Haskell será um grande bem para você!**](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/chapters) - Completo e didático.
2. [**Programação Funcional com a Linguagem Haskell**](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/andrey/ci062/ProgramacaoHaskell.pdf)
3. [**Learn You a Haskell**](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) - Inglês

Answer (score 3):

### A melhor fonte de apredizado de Scala que eu já tive

**https://pt.coursera.org/course/progfun**

Neste curso, você aprenderá interativamente, com o criador da linguagem Scala - Martin Odersky-, além disso, você terá excelentes bases de programação funcional.

Realmente, fez uma diferença pra mim. Infelizmente apenas em inglês por enquanto sem legendas em português.

Comment: Olá, Filipe! Excelente recomendação.

Comment: Muito Obrigada Filipe, vou dar uma olhada... confesso que não tinha me lembrado do coursera.